# Retrofit Response

Tags: android, retrofit

So i have this JSON Response from a server:

```
{
    "result": {
        "id": 30,
        "status": "Successful."
    }
}
```

And a java class where:

```
public class JSONResponse {
    @SerializedName("result")
    public JsonObject res;
    @SerializedName("id")
    public int id;
    @SerializedName("status")
    public String msg;
}
```

And here is where i call the service:

```
customerResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<CustomerRequestResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CustomerRequestResponse> call, Response<CustomerRequestResponse> response) {
               response.body().res.get(String.valueOf(response.body().id));
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Registed Successfully!!!" + "\n" + "User ID = " + response.body().id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// this  your result

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CustomerRequestResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("response-failure", call.toString());
            }
        });
```

And i want to be able to get the value of the id when there is a response from server. How do i go about this? Please Help

Comment: Can you post your Retrofit Client code please? also your CustomerRequestResponse class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you JSONResponse as below; because JSON you're getting has JSONObject `result`

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class CustomerRequestResponse{

@SerializedName("result")
@Expose
private Result result;

public Result getResult() {
return result;
}

public void setResult(Result result) {
this.result = result;
}

}
```

**Result Class**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Result {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

}
```

**Change your code as**

```
customerResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<CustomerRequestResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CustomerRequestResponse> call, Response<CustomerRequestResponse> response) {
                Integer id =  response.body().getResult().getId();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Registered Successfully!!!" + "\n" + "User ID = " + id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// this  your result

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CustomerRequestResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("response-failure", call.toString());
            }
        });
```

Comment: _because JSON you're getting has JSONArray result_. `result` is `JSONObject` not `JSONArray`.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what am looking for. I have gotten the result but i specifically wanted to get the value of the id. I tried your method but it, as tried to get the response.body() there is no way that i can get the id.

Comment: Thank you @Piyush :) My bad.. but Fixed now !

Comment: @S.Jay have you added my code for fetching response ?